# when parameter value is omitted in stored procedure, want it to display for all values

Tags: sql-server-2005

in a stored procedure, when a parameter value is not specified, i want it to display result for all values in the column.

I tried the code as below but if I leave blank the parameter field1 while executing it, it doesn't work and asks to supply the field1 value.

```
create procedure procedurename
declare @startdate datetime, @enddate endtime, @field1 varchar(15)

select * from table1
where field1 = @xyz or @xyz is null
and date between @startdate and @enddate

execute procedurename @startdate = '01/07/2012', @enddate = '31/07/2012'
```

*[i omitted field1 value so that it should display result for all values in field1 column between the two dates]* but it asks for parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to omit the field on the call, you need to supply a default value in the declaration of the procedure.

```
create procedure procedurename (
    @startdate datetime, 
    @enddate endtime, 
    @field1 varchar(15) = NULL
)
AS
...
```